# POST request in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, post, request

Main task is POST-autorization via Delphi program. Using the REST Client I found that, having url of site and two headers:  *login_email* and *login_pass* I can successfully get the HTML codу and my POST auth form is OK, I'm logged in.

However, I wrote this Delphi code:

```
DataToSend := TStringList.Create;
DataToSend.Add('');

IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('login_email','some_email');
IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('login_pass','some_password');

Memo1.Lines.Add(idHTTP1.Post('http://url.com', DataToSend));
```

My custom headers are not URL encoded.

I see the request headers:

```
Server: nginx/1.0.8
Date: Sun, 01 Sep 2013 17:03:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.6-1+lenny16
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

but ontained HTML is same page, for which POST-request has been sent with unprocessed form.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Some servers rejects the requests due to the default `User-Agent` set by Indy. If that's your case, you may try to fill the `IdHTTP1.Request.UserAgent` property with one of the favorite browsers to fake the server that you are browser. But it's just my guess (and quite a frequent problem).

Comment: I've added this Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.62 Safari/537.36 as UserAgent, but nothing's changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The POST request parameters never includes in HTTP header.
Try that:

```
DataToSend := TStringList.Create;
DataToSend.Add('login_email=some_email');
DataToSend.Add('login_pass=some_password');
IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

Memo1.Lines.Add(idHTTP1.Post('http://url.com', DataToSend));
```