# Delphi XE6 post request and indy

Tags: android, delphi, indy, delphi-xe6

I have a Delphi XE6 application which I would like to install on an Android phone. I am testing it on a Windows platform. Below is my unit source code. On my form I have a button, idHttp Indy tool and a Memo Field.

The problem is that when I click the button I get the error

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden.

But I can access the site through my browser, so the page isn't forbidden.
Can anyone see a problem?

I have searched for how to do post requests using firemonkey and delphi and I found these links:

- [How to send a HTTP Post Request in Delphi 2010 using WinInet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2977720/how-to-send-a-http-post-request-in-delphi-2010-using-wininet)
- [POST request in Delphi XE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560799/post-request-in-delphi-xe)
- [How are parameters sent in an HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request)

None of which help me.

```
unit Start_Interface_u;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes,
  System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.StdCtrls,
  IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection, IdTCPClient, IdHTTP,
  FMX.Layouts, FMX.Memo;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnLogin: TButton;
    IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

  {$R *.fmx}


  procedure TForm1.btnLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
  Var
    sResult: String;
    DataToSend :TStringList;
  begin

  DataToSend := TStringList.Create;
  //DataToSend.Add('login_email=some_email');
  //DataToSend.Add('login_pass=some_password');
  IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

  Memo1.Lines.Add(idHTTP1.Post('http://mysite.co.za/dash.php', DataToSend));

  end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to set the user agent to simulate a common web browser, for example (taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4573746/80901) answer)

```
Request.UserAgent := 
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0b8) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0b8';
```

Answer (score 0):

`403` means that HTTP layer authentication is missing or sending incorrect credentials. `TIdHTTP` uses a plugin architecture for handling HTTP authentication. You need to add various `IdAuthentication...` units, or the  `IdAllAuthentications` unit, to your `uses` clause to enable the desired HTTP authentications that Indy supports, like NTLM or Digest. There is also an `TIdHTTP.OnSelectAuthorization` event for finer control over which authentication type to use if the server supports multiple types, and an `TIdHTTP.OnAuthorization` event for prompting you for new credentials whenever the server asks for them.